# RAD Studio XE8 error creating form

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I've installed RAD Studio XE8 Trial, but I've got this error when i create a Multi-Device Application Project

```
Error Creating form: Cannot Create Texture for 'TCanvasD2D'
```

anyone knows?

Comment: Is your DirectX up to date?  What OS are you running?  Direct2D requires Vista SP2 + Platform Update or higher.  Win7 should have SP1.

Comment: Make sure that your computer meets the requirements as outlined [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites)

Comment: i try on my Win Server 2012, 
I've XE7 installed, but no problem with it....

Comment: Don't guess. @whosrdaddy gave you a link to the requirements; run DXInfo on your machine and see if it meets them.

Comment: From the link supplied by @whosrdaddy : `Microsoft Windows Server® 2008 and 2012 (32-bit and 64-bit) are supported only for deployment of apps. `

Comment: so, what it's mean sir...
i can't create multi-device application with my Win Server 2012? help

Comment: reread what @J... just said, Win 2012 is only supported for **deployment** of apps, not for **development**.

Comment: Okay thank you Sir...., I'll try on my another machine now.