# Variable Height TListView Item in FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4.2

I tried the sample from Alister Christie "[Variable Height TListView Item in FMX](https://youtu.be/usZTvYSMvFM?t=528)" but I have an issue. When I bind the image to the ListView, I get the following message:

[image]

which translates to:

> The exception EBindCompError was raised with the message 'EvalError
> in LinkListControlToField1: impossible to create a texture for TCanvasD2D'.

Comment: On which operating system are you developing/executing? [Not every is supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30214455/4299358), so you have to be precise about which Windows version/variant you use.

Comment: Ok.I use a Windows 10 pro

Comment: Check if you meet all [FireMonkey requirements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites).

Comment: Already done and it's ok